# Build failed with "package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist" error in Azure DevOps

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, apache-poi

As I run my below script to read data from excel functionality locally no issues in the execution.

```
public String getCellDataString(String sheetName, int rowNum, int colNum) throws IOException {      
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/excel/ExcelWorkBook.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);           
        String cellData = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum).getStringCellValue();             
        return cellData;                                                                         
}
```

I have all apache-poi added to pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```

As I upload to Azure DevOps and build, I get a package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel does not exist error for each of the imports and build failed.

- package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist
- cannot find symbol

[image: Click here to see Azure DevOps Build failed error]

I did tried below links but could not find any solution,

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809709/package-org-apache-poi-ss-usermodel-does-not-exist)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878341/cannot-import-xssf-in-apache-poi)

I see that Azure Devops unable to download sources, May I please know what am I missing ?

EDITED:
Below is my Azure DevOps pipeline definition
[image: Azure DevOps Pipeline Definition]

Comment: Don't mix POI jars from different versions. See [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204). So don't mix versions `4.1.2` and `4.1.1`. And don't use the old `openxml4j` version `1.0-beta` with `apache poi 4.1.2`. The current `openxml4j` is part of `poi-ooxml` now.

Comment: Does this issue persist? Could you please share some details about your pipeline definitions so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Kindly find my updated pipeline definition above.

Comment: What if you use maven command in command line locally to do same job? I'm trying to figure out whether there's something wrong from project itself or pipeline settings.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I don't see any issues when I run locally. Below is my maven command looks like,

clean test -Dusername=username -Dpassword=password -Denvironment=URL -Dbrowser=chrome